# Корректность предложения

Tags: стилистика

Корректно ли составлено предложение: «В качестве источника доказательств эти материалы используются при установлении трех групп обстоятельств, подлежащих установлению по уголовному делу»?

Answer (score 1):

в юриспруденции допустимо - у них такие формулировки, которые простым смертным кажутся корявыми - но у них так принято и менять иногда нельзя: таков порядок. Хотя, конечно, читается все это отвратительно.

Answer (score 0):

Дважды слово "установление" - нужно одно из них заменить подходящим по смыслу синонимом. И порядок слов я бы сделала более традиционным: «Эти материалы используются в качестве источника доказательств при определении (?)трех групп обстоятельств, подлежащих установлению по уголовному делу»

Comment: Корректно ли составлено предложение: «В качестве источника доказательств эти материалы используются при установлении трех групп обстоятельств, подлежащих установлению по уголовному делу»?

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело не в сложности юриспруденции, а в терминологии, которую нужно соблюдать.

Например, существует термин "установление фактов", который определяется следующим образом: "Суд устанавливает факты, имеющие юридическое значение, лишь при невозможности получения заявителем в ином порядке надлежащих документов, удостоверяющих эти факты, либо при невозможности восстановления утраченных документов".

Из этого примера следует, что юридические термины не следует изменять.

Слово "установление" определяется как "обнаружив, определить, выяснить". Оно  имеет несколько  синонимов (определение, диагностирование, выяснение, обнаружение), однако в юридических текстах замену синонимом сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно ли составлено предложение: «В качестве источника доказательств эти материалы используются при установлении трех групп обстоятельств, подлежащих установлению по уголовному делу»?
Я бы исправила так. Как доказательства эти материалы используются при установлении трех групп обстоятельств по уголовному делу. По - моему, и с терминологией всё в порядке, и со смыслом.